# How to split graphs in two halves (15 days each)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to split graph in two halves of 15 day each using dates

[image]

i have tried using Top N filters Top and Bottom but when date range is changed i have duplicated graphs.

[image]

Split is happening using above filter but when i reduce date filter range duplicate data is shown in two graphs

[image]

i tried Flag = IF(DAY(MAX('Table'[Date]))<=15,1,2) as well but was getting data not in sequential  order

[image: not in seq order]

I'm new to this any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I just split it in half, rather than by 15 days. But you could change the math to use 15 days instead, if that's what you still want. Regardless, seeing this might help.

I started with a table like this, called Sheet1:

[image]

Then I created a chart like your original:

[image]

Then I created this DAX measure:

```
Chart Selector = 
var minDate = CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(Sheet1[Date]), ALL(Sheet1[Date]))
var maxDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(Sheet1[Date]), ALL(Sheet1[Date]))
var midDate = minDate + (DATEDIFF(minDate, maxDate, DAY)/2)

return
IF(CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Date]),FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Date]<=midDate)),"First","Second")
```

(You could change the midDate variable's calculation, above, to one that does 15 days instead.)

Then I made two copies of the chart and, in each copy, I added the new measure to the chart's filters. In the first chart's filter, I filtered for if it contains "First." For the second chart's filter, I filtered for if it contains "Second."

[image]
[image]

My end result looks like this:

[image]